# syslog-ng leaving empty log files after rotation

Tags: cron, logrotate

Let me start by saying I am new to syslog-ng and logrotation and am doing this at home to learn.

I have log files that are being sent to my syslog server from my router and are logging no problem and will rotate, compress, and move to them to a different directory.

After the rotation it will create the new log file for the new day, compress the old one and move it but it will leave a copy yesterdays log file blank.  There will be a compressed version of the log in my archive directory as well. As a result I end up with the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm     0 Jul 18 00:00 router.2019.07.17.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root adm   50M Jul 18 06:52 router.2019.07.18.log
```

syslog-ng file

```
/var/log/router/router*.log
{
        rotate 2
        daily
        compress
        missingok
        notifempty
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

I do have a cron job that forces all this to run and move the file which I don't suspect is the issue.  Here is a copy of the section in my syslog-ng.conf file that relates to my router:

```
# router ###########
# Add Filter to add our router
filter f_router { host( "192.168.X.X" ); };
# Add destination file where logs will be stored
#destination df_router { file("/home/pi/files/router.log"); };
log { source ( s_net ); filter( f_router ); destination ( df_router ); };
destination df_router {
file("/var/log/router/router.${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}.log"
template-escape(no));
};
```